# How do I hide the AJAX Cart block when cart is empty?

Tags: 6, blocks, ajax, ubercart

How can I **hide [Ubercart AJAX Cart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ajax_cart) block when the user's shopping cart is empty**?

I know I could hide it with some jQuery tricks (for example, looking for the "cart-empty" class under my AJAX cart block (which has the class "block-uc_ajax_cart"), and hide the whole block if I found it), but this way I also would have to solve if cart is updated... Too messy.

I haven't found any opportunities to hide the block in this case under block settings, nor under the AJAX Cart Settings (`http://<mysite>/admin/store/settings/uc_ajax_cart`).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in the meantime I found the solution.

1.) Set **"Block title"** in the appropriate block configuration to **`<none>`**. (`http://<mysite>/admin/build/block/configure/uc_ajax_cart/0`) (you'll see later why)

Block title:
`<none>`

2.) **Copy the UC AJAX Cart template files** (`uc_ajax_cart_block_content.tpl.php`, `uc_ajax_cart_block_content_empty.tpl.php`) from `http://<mysite>/sites/all/modules/uc_ajax_cart/templates/`
to your own theme's `templates` directory (`http://<mysite>//sites/all/themes/<mytheme>/templates/`).

3.) After that, **open both copied files** (which are now in your template directory) **in a text editor**.

4.) **Delete** (or put in a comment) the content of `uc_ajax_cart_block_content_empty.tpl.php`, and upload the edited file to the server.

5.) **Prepend** the following to `uc_ajax_cart_block_content.tpl.php` to have the block title back:

```html
<h2 class="title">
    <span class="title block-title" id="ajax-cart-headline">
        <a href="#" id="ajaxCartToggleView" class="ajax-cart-processed"><?php print t('Shopping cart')?></a>
    </span>
</h2>
```

(The rest should stay intact!!)

6.) **Clear the theme registry cache** (`http://<mysite>/admin_menu/flush-cache/theme`), and you're done.

---

UPDATE:
the method above breaks the toggling opportunity of the shopping cart content (if the following is checked in the settings: *"Make the shopping cart block collapsible by clicking the name or arrow."*) when clicking on the block title (*"Shopping Cart"*), because the title part is also updated with AJAX from the `uc_ajax_cart_block_content.tpl.php` file, BUT there IS a solution in jQuery, which you have to put in your own JavaScript-file (which is e.g. put in your theme's .info file), and it looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    if( $('#ajaxCartToggleView').length > 0 ){
        // live: "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future." (http://api.jquery.com/live/)
        $("#ajaxCartToggleView").live("click", function(){
            ajaxCartToggleView();
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```